# Retrieving data in Ascending order In PHP5 MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

```
if($limit== '400'){
    $sql="SELECT * FROM report ORDER BY reportID ASC LIMIT $limit WHERE userID='$reportID'";}
```

says `"You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE userID='147'' at line 1"`.

Anybody who can help me. I'm a beginner in php programming language.

Answer (score 1):

`Where` clause should be come before the `Order By`

Try this:

```
if($limit== '400'){
    $sql="SELECT * FROM report WHERE userID='$reportID' ORDER BY reportID ASC LIMIT $limit";
}
```

Comment: Still it's not working!

Comment: what is the error now?

Comment: Thank you! now it's working!

Comment: You are welcome! glad to hear :)

Comment: <?php $cidmID =$_SESSION['cidmid'];
$query = "SELECT * FROM  report WHERE cidmid='$cidmID' AND forwarded,COUNT(forwarded) WHERE viewd='Not seen'";                      $result = mysql_query($query) or die (mysql_error());
while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
echo "[".$row['COUNT(forwarded)']."]"; }?> </a> </li>  but it says "Notice: Undefined index: cidmid in C:\.\.\.\cidm.php on line 58
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'COUNT(forwarded) WHERE viewd='Not seen'' at line 1".

Comment: $query = "SELECT * FROM report WHERE cidmid='$cidmID' AND viewd='Not seen'";

Comment: You need to pay attention on mysql syntax and query builder.

Comment: Thank you Very much! but still I can't count 'not seen' reports by cidmid it says "Notice: Undefined index: cidmid in C:\xampp\htdocs\AA\reports.php on line 58" and php $cidmID =$_SESSION['cidmid'];is not working

Comment: @Eskinder you comments not related to the question you asked. This the issue in application logic. Try to debug and correct that.

Comment: Also try search for topic ` handling session in php` might help you understand and fix the session issue.